# What is the best way to access Rest services that secured with OAuth security?

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, oauth, resttemplate

I want to access REST web services written by other vendors. But the problem is the OAuth security. I got username, password, consumer key and consumer secret from them.

First I call to a service to get refresh token. This is the response

```
{
   "scope": "PRODUCTION",
   "token_type": "bearer",
   "expires_in": 3148,
   "refresh_token": "315381713fc905a8c5f586d5145bd84",
   "access_token": "46ed281862dc48d2d46372fc2e84e5"
}
```

Got the refresh_token with expire time. Must I keep this token in database or memory until it expires and only call this service again to get refresh token after that refresh token expires.

I don't know how to keep this refresh and access tokens in my side(Database or Memory). Please help me to find a better way to access this services.

Comment: Access and refresh tokens are not supposed to be posted publicly. They are your "secret keys". It's good you did not provide your "PRODUCTION" API endpoints :)

Comment: yes. This tokens are not real ones. I edit them and post here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases, you would like to keep the access and refresh tokens longer than your application process. In other words, you don't want to re-authenticate again. That's why it would be better if you save your tokens in persistent storage (DB, file, etc.).

You can simplify your code by using existing oAuth clients for Java. Some popular examples are:

- [Spring Security oAuth](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/)
- [Apache Oltu](https://oltu.apache.org/)
- [List of libs](http://oauth.net/2/) on official oAuth website

The oAuth result seems standard JSON result from oAuth Server. So configuring one of the libs should not raise any problems.

Comment: Is there any standard procedure to handle them like store DB after encryption and what is the best way to identify whether token expire or not (calling to service or comparing "expires_in" time limit) ?

Comment: No, there is not "standard procedure". As always, this things depend on your context. But anyhow, in most cases, you would want to persist them across your application relaunches. So, a good option would be to persist it in DB, in middleware (cache layer maybe) or some temp file, but read it out into memory for performance. Regarding your second question. You can request to update your access token just before its expiry by checking the period or you can do that at first error response from oAuth server.

Comment: @samithkumarasingha, if you are wondering about these details, I would highly recommend using an existing library. Because, the ones in my answer do all these automatically for you and you can concentrate on your business logic. Also, there are some security nuances that you still need to consider like setting random strings while getting request tokens from web client, etc. Otherwise, MiM attack is possible.